# DataSvcUtil.exe and generating a custom namespace

Tags: wcf-data-services

I am using DataSvcUtil and I wanted to generate a custom namespace for my generated class but this does not seem to be allowed.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSvcUtil.exe is a fairly thin wrapper over the System.Data.Services.Design.EntityClassGenerator class, which has support for using a custom [namespace prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679652.aspx), but not arbitrarily customizing the namespaces. I don't know of a specific reason this support was not provided, there may not have been a compelling enough scenario for it at the time.

If you need more flexible code generation, I strongly suggest you take a look at the [T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/07/02/trying-out-the-prerelease-odata-client-t4-template.aspx) the team released some time ago. It is very likely that code generation for WCF Data Services will more towards using T4 rather than DataSvcUtil/EntityClassGenerator.